# Getting data from Arduino WebSocket sendBIN to Javascript as Blob

Tags: javascript, websocket, arduino

I'm really struggling with trying to get data from blob in Javascript.

The blob is from ArduinoWebSocket sendBin which is a uint8_t array of 4 elements.

I debug the Javascript and get

```
e.data: Blob {size: 4, type: "", slice: function}
```

I've tried using FileReader from other examples like:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.data);
reader.onloadend = (event) => {
  // The contents of the BLOB are in reader.result:
  console.log(reader.result);
}
```

I can see in debug

```
reader.result: ArrayBuffer {byteLength: 4}
```

But there is no way to see the data. I can see ArrayBuffer Prototype but as I drill down into that it just keeps going.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer. My own ignorance of ArrayBuffer. It has to be assigned to the correct array type as follows:

```
connection.onmessage = function(e) {
  reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result); // Key line!!!
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.data);
};
```

Now "data" will contain the data from the ArrayBuffer (provided that the correct type of array is wrapped around reader.result);